# How to remove inception words in list?

Tags: python, list, nested

Given a list with some "inception" words, how to remove the inception words? How find the bigger inception words?

Let's define inception words as words that are part of a larger word that occurs in the same list.

**The Task**:

> To make it very clear, if a list contains ['a', 'b', 'a b c'], removes
>   'a' and 'b' because there is an element that contains 'a' and 'b' that
>   is bigger itself.

**Example 1**, [in]:

```
[u'dose rate', u'object', u'dose', u'rate', u'computation']
```

[out]:

```
[u'dose rate', u'object',u'computation']
```

**Example 2**, [in]:

```
[u'shift', u'magnetic', u'system', u'magnetic sensor', u'phase shift', u'phase', u'output', u'sensor', u'sensing', u'sensor system']
```

Since 'magnetic', 'sensor', 'system', 'magnetic sensor' and 'sensor system' exists, we can either:

Desired output, [out]:

```
[u'system', u'magnetic sensor', u'phase shift', u'output', u'sensing']
```

or [out]:

```
[u'magnetic'u'phase shift', u'output', u'sensing', u'sensor system']
```

---

**I've tried** the following but it's not getting the desired outputs:

```
ls = [u'dose rate', u'object', u'dose', u'rate', u'computation']
>>> set([i for i in ls for j in ls if i!=j or i not in j])
set([u'dose rate', u'object', u'rate', u'computation', u'dose'])
>>> set([j for i in ls for j in ls if i!=j or i not in j])
set([u'rate', u'object', u'dose rate', u'computation', u'dose'])
>>> set([j for j in ls for i in ls if i!=j or i not in j])
set([u'dose rate', u'object', u'rate', u'computation', u'dose'])
```

Comment: Add the bad outputs, so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Try doing this in a standard for loop. List comprehensions are nice for concisely expressing simple loops, but in this case a simple loop will help you understand what's actually happening and help you debug the code.

Comment: @Jongware, the bad outputs are in the line after the list comprehensions.

Comment: Your definition of inception words is contradicted by your 2nd example, rendering your question impossible to answer correctly.

Comment: @Shashank, the 2nd example allows both outputs as valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to satisfy the first example you can do something like,

```
>>> words = [u'dose rate', u'object', u'dose', u'rate', u'computation']
>>> [w1 for w1 in words if not any(w1 in w2 for w2 in words if w2 != w1)]
[u'dose rate', u'object', u'computation']
```

But your second example demonstrates that your requirements are a bit more complicated. You cannot use the same small word more than once to form a string.

Unfortunately a one-liner won't be possible. Try something like,

```
def remove_comprising(words):
    seen = set()
    result_words = []
    for word in words:
        for small_word in words:
            if small_word in word and small_word != word:
                if small_word in seen:
                    word = word.replace(small_word, '')
                else:
                    seen.add(small_word)
        result_words.append(word)
    return [word.strip() for word in result_words if word not in seen]
```

Then we get the correct results for both example 1,

```
>>> words = [u'dose rate', u'object', u'dose', u'rate', u'computation']
>>> remove_comprising(words)
[u'dose rate', u'object', u'computation']
```

And example 2,

```
>>> words = [u'shift', u'magnetic', u'system', u'magnetic sensor', u'phase shift', u'phase', u'output', u'sensor', u'sensing', u'sensor system']
>>> remove_comprising(words)
[u'magnetic sensor', u'phase shift', u'output', u'sensing', u'system']
```

Answer (score 2):

Given a **list of words**:

```
>>> words = [u'dose rate', u'object', u'dose', u'rate', u'computation']
```

and a definition of what an **inception word** is:

```
>>> inception = lambda x: any(x in w for w in words if len(x) < len(w))
```

we can construct a list of 'non inception words' like this:

```
>>> [w for w in words if not inception(w)]
[u'dose rate', u'object', u'computation']
```

Comment: I do not understand how example two is a solution to your problem though, shouldn't 'system' be removed since the list contains 'sensor system'?

Unless I fail to understand something, I think that you must revise either your definition of a inception word or example 2.

(My example remove words that "are part of a bigger word in the same list".)

Comment: I believe he means that a small word should be used once to form another string, then removed. In that case "system" would still be there because you only removed the "sensor" first part.

Comment: In that case, the definition of an inception word is incorrect ("Let's define inception words as words that are part of a larger word that occurs in the same list.").

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a complex function to read: not pythonic in its implementation, but should solve the problem.

The basic idea is this: evaluate and flag each word in your list if it should be included or not. 
Then using that flag, actually print out the words.

The trouble is you want to find words which can be part of 2 other larger words, which makes the flagging a little more granular (not simply keep or reject, but keep,  continued keep and reject)

```
import copy
def inception(wordlist):

    # dont want to mutilate original list
    new_wordlist = copy.deepcopy(wordlist)

    # find length of wordlist to know when original length is traversed
    word_count = len(new_wordlist)
    output_set = set()
    output_list = [] # flags existence, -1 = evaluation postponed, 0 = exclude, 1= include
    eval_list = []

    # iterate through list
    for idx, word in enumerate(new_wordlist):
        inner_words = word.split()

        # if its only 1 word, evaluate at the end 
        # Can be made smarter to reject earlier
        if len(inner_words) == 1 and idx < word_count:
            output_list.append(-1)
            eval_list.append(word)
            new_wordlist.append(word)
            continue        

        # Flag existence of inner words if they haven't been found
        existence = 0
        for in_wrd in inner_words:
            if in_wrd in output_set:
                output_list.append(0)       
            else:
                # keep continued 
                existence += 1
                output_set.add(in_wrd)
                output_list.append(existence)
            eval_list.append(in_wrd)

    # now evaluate by position of flags
    final_set = set()
    for idx, word in enumerate(eval_list):
        if output_list[idx] > 0:

            # combine if words are in order
            if output_list[idx] > 1:
                final_set.remove(eval_list[idx-1])
                word = ' '.join([eval_list[idx-1], eval_list[idx]])
            final_set.add(word) 
    return list(final_set)
```

I've only tested it with the 2 sets you've provided. If you have sets with which this fails, please add them to the comments, i'd like to course correct.